#  Nested GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, hierarchy

I have a hierarchy of grid views which are nested. To be specific: I have a grid view (say dt2) nested inside a grid view (say dt1). Now, I have many small grid views nested inside a nested grid view (dt2), and I want to fill the grid views inside it, which I am finding tedious as the rowdatabound event of dt2 is not getting fired unlike the event of dt1.

Comment: Show your code, otherwise this question doesn't get answered well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many articles out there on how to do this; I found [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28276/DataGridView-with-hierarchical-data-binding) to be most helpful.  It doesn't appear all that complicated.

Display columns:

```
List<string> displayColumns = new List<string>();
displayColumns.Add("id");
displayColumns.Add("Name");
displayColumns.Add("Fruit");
displayColumns.Add("BoughtFrom");
displayColumns.Add("Date");
```

Grouping:

```
List<GroupColumn> groupColumns = new List<GroupColumn>();
groupColumns.Add(new GroupColumn("Quantity", GroupTypeEnum.Sum));
```

Relational DataSet:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Your connection string");
connection.Open();

SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "SELECT id, Name, Fruit FROM FruitPrefs",
    connection);
DataTable dtResult1 = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dtResult1);

dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "SELECT id, BoughtFrom, Date, Quantity FROM SalesRecords",
    connection);
DataTable dtResult2 = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dtResult2);

DataSet dsResults = new DataSet("Results");
dsResults.Tables.Add(dtResult1);
dsResults.Tables.Add(dtResult2);
DataRelation relation1 = new DataRelation(
    "relation1",
    dtResult1.Columns["id"],
    dtResult2.Columns["id"]);
dsResults.Relations.Add(relation1);
```

Binding:

```
DataGridSource newGridSource = new DataGridSource(
    dtResult1.DataSet,
    displayColumns,
    groupColumns);
hierarchicalGridView1.DataSource = newGridSource;
```